# After every setup:upgrade I need to give permission (Debien)

Tags: magento2.3

I'm using Magento2 on Debien 8, and after every change, I lunch the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

The problem here is when I lunch this command I need to give permission to magento folder using this command on Debien terminal

`chmod -R 0777 magento2` (the folder)

is there any solution to fix that ?

Comment: Run the upgrade using as the www-data user `sudo -u www-data php/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: @MackieeE `Can't create directory /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open following file in terminal

```
vim /etc/apache2/envvars
```

check the user for apache

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=root
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=root
```

Change the user appropritely which your bin/magento commands assign the files you are generating.

The one time change user permission for your magento folder like

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data magento2
```

Then after it should work.